# Heroku node.js Procfile for script not in root

Tags: node.js, heroku

My aim is to create a groupme bot using heroku and node.js https://github.com/whitec54/shouts-things

I'm pretty new to web development so maybe this is glaring but I can't seem to fix my heroku application error.

This is the message returned by the logs:

```
2016-07-26T01:44:52.756548+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-26T01:44:53.848661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node routes/index.js`
2016-07-26T01:44:55.966222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-07-26T01:45:09.474760+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shouts-things.herokuapp.com request_id=19173085-e8ed-4a85-8cd9-90c96b7347f6 fwd="108.178.113.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-26T01:45:08.701288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shouts-things.herokuapp.com request_id=f29fef93-7530-4c1e-9724-73884694b457 fwd="108.178.113.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

this error is seems better than what I started with but I'm not sure where to go from here. In spite of the reading I've done my understanding of how Procfiles work in heroku is pretty weak.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Procfile` it has mentioned to start `routes/index.js` which doesn't have any code to run the express server. You should be having this route registered on `app.js` and start app.js with node.

`express-generator` npm will help you get started with the basic scaffolding required for a nodejs project.

Comment: Does that mean I should declare a web process type for app.js because I'm calling the router to handle requests from within it? Further, do I only mention scripts that call others and those that are called by another script don't need to be included?